# Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | HTMLFormElement' in Vue Typescript EmailJS Project

Tags: typescript, forms, vuejs3

I'm pretty new to Vue and I'm trying to create a simple form using Emailjs and Typescript. I can't seem to find a similar issue to this and I'm not sure what the issue is with this.$refs.form. No matter what I do, I can't seem to get rid of the "Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | HTMLFormElement'" error. Can someone explain to me what my issue is? This method is straight from the emailjs documentation.

Here is my script:

```
<script lang="ts">
import emailjs from '@emailjs/browser'

export default {
  methods: {
    sendEmail() {
      emailjs
        .sendForm('service_wu6mj7b', 'template_hxo8y4h', this.$refs.form, 'wdqa23HmG2helkMuFGDY0')
        .then(
          (result: { text: any }) => {
            console.log('SUCCESS!', result.text)
          },
          (error: { text: any }) => {
            console.log('FAILED...', error.text)
          }
        )
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Here is my template:

```
<template>
  <h1 class="text-center text-5xl font-bold pt-5">Terrarium Order Form</h1>
  <form ref="form" @submit.prevent="sendEmail()">
    <div class="mx-64 px-10 py-5 mt-10 bg-white">
      <p>
        <label class="text-2xl font-bold">Your Name:</label>
        <br />
        <span>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            placeholder="Your Name"
            class="border-2 border-[#d2d2d2] w-full text-black rounded-md pl-4 font-bold"
          />
        </span>
      </p>
      <p class="pt-5">
        <label class="text-2xl font-bold">Your Email Address:</label>
        <br />
        <span>
          <input
            type="email"
            name="email"
            placeholder="Your Email Address"
            class="border-2 border-[#d2d2d2] w-full text-black rounded-md pl-4 font-bold"
          />
        </span>
      </p>
      <p class="pt-5">
        <label class="text-2xl font-bold">Your Phone Number:</label>
        <br />
        <span>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="phone"
            placeholder="Your Phone Number"
            class="border-2 border-[#d2d2d2] w-full text-black rounded-md pl-4 font-bold"
          />
        </span>
      </p>
      <p class="pt-5">
        <label class="text-2xl font-bold">Your Phone Number:</label>
        <br />
        <span>
          <input type="submit" value="Send" />
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </form>
</template>
```

I've looked for similar issues and explanations as well as Vue, Typescript, Emailjs projects and found nothing.

Comment: Which specific line is causing the error? Is it the third argument of emailjs.sendForm?If so, have you tried casting this.$refs.form to HTMLFormElement (as in that third argument changes to `this.$refs.form as HTMLFormElement` via TS type assertion: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions)?

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much! I knew it was something so simple. I feel silly that this was the solution